# wix/react-native-navigation V2 | setRoot bottomTabs in second screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

Initially at first screen,

```
const appLaunchedListener = Navigation.events().registerAppLaunchedListener(() => {
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
       component: {
          name: 'StartScreen',
       }
    }
  });
});
```

Then, using `Navigation.push(...)` to new page, at this point onwards I want to start using `bottomTabs`. 
I have tried this at NewScreen:

```
Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    bottomTabs: {
      children: [
        {
          stack: {
            children: [{
              component: {
                name: 'NewScreen',
              },
            }],
            options: {
              bottomTab: {
                text: 'NEW',
                icon: {
                  scale: 15,
                  uri: 'new_grey'
                },
                selectedIcon: {
                  scale: 15,
                  uri: 'new_gold'
                },
              }
            },
          },
        },
        {
          stack: {
            children: [{
              component: {
                name: 'NotificationScreen',
              },
            }],
            options: {
              bottomTab: {
                text: 'NOTIFICATION',
                icon: {
                  scale: 15,
                  uri: 'notification_grey'
                },
                selectedIcon: {
                  scale: 15,
                  uri: 'notification_gold'
                },
              }
            },
          },
        },
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

With my codes now, the bottom tabs does not appear. 
How can I achieved my expceted result? 
With V1, I can just use these handler: `startSingleScreenApp(...)` & `startTabBasedApp(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes provided already worked fine. The problem lies in where to put the codes.

You can call the `Navigation.setRoot(...)` again in any of your screen but it should be inside of the exported class.
Like this:

```
...

export default class NewScreen {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  startTabScreen = () => {
    const tabs = [{ ... }];

    Navigation.setRoot({
      root: {
        bottomTabs: {
          children: tabs
        }
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.startTabScreen();
  }

  ...

}
```